# Detect isolated facets in mesh CGAL

Tags: c++, cgal

How can I locate isolated facets (or group of facets) in a mesh using CGAL? Let's suppose I have a mesh file (STL, OBJ, ...), and I know it contains a closed solid and a group of facets that does not constitute another solid and is not connected to the aforementioned solid present in the file: how do I detect that isolated group of facets?
For example, I can read an .STL file using CGAL::IO::read_STL(), but then I'm not able to do what I'm asking. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have not a triangle soup but a Polyhedron or Surface_mesh. Im this case you can call the [`connected_components()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__keep__connected__components__grp.html#gad417b04f530806789515a25530547a36) function